# I am trying to clear typeorm mysql database on server shutdown (NestJS)

Tags: mysql, typescript, express, nestjs, typeorm

How do I delete all entries in my database on server shutdown?

```
export class RoomsService {
  async onApplicationShutdown() {
    await this.roomService.deleteAll()
  }
```

```
async deleteAll(): Promise<DeleteResult> {
    const res = await this.roomRepository.delete('*');
    return res;
  }
```

On shutdown I get this error (even when I don't use async await)

```
Error: Pool is closed.
at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\sites\UltimatePartyRoom\upr-server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\pool.js:39:40
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
```

Comment: this might be a bug related to this issue: https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/1614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on application shutdown point (`onApplicationShutdown`) the database connection is already disconnected so you need clear database before reaching this point.

Use `OnModuleDestroy` instead:

```js
export class RoomsService implements OnModuleDestroy {
  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.roomService.deleteAll()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but beforeApplicationShutdown turned out to work best for me, onModuleDestroy gave me the same error.